# Which properties of p-adic representations can be recovered from (\varphi,\Gamma)-modules?

Tags: galois-representations, hodge-theory, nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory

In Berger's "[An introduction to the Theory of $p$-adic Representations](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0210184)", he mentions that due the the equivalence of categories between etale $(\varphi,\Gamma)$-modules and $p$-adic representations, it should be possible to recover **all** properties of $p$-adic representations in terms of $(\varphi,\Gamma)$-modules.

For example, in Herr's 1998 PhD thesis, he shows that the Galois cohomology $H^{i}(-,V)$ of a $p$-adic representation $V$ can be obtained from a complex involving the fixed elements under torsion of the Dieudonne module $\mathbb{D}(V)$.

Since Berger wrote in 2002, which properties do people think can (easily?) be recovered and which have so far?

Comment: This question is really hard to interpret. Berger shows in his articles how to recover things like $D_{cris}(V)$ and $D_{st}(V)$ and so on directly from the $(\phi,\Gamma)$-module. You've said yourself how to recover the Galois cohomology. What is left? I am finding it hard to think of a property that is natural but which is not dealt with in the paper you reference. Can you give one specific example of a property that you don't know how to recover from the $(\phi,\Gamma)$-module?

Comment: I've heard Colmez say that he doesn't know how to extract the $\varepsilon$-factor of a p-adic representation from its $(\varphi, \Gamma)$-module.

Comment: Well that sounds like a good answer to James' question! I'm a little confused though. Can't one read the $\epsilon$-factor off from $D_{cris}$? Or is this some fancier $\epsilon$-factor?
<p>
Regardless of all this I still find the question hard to interpret in the following sense: Colmez _does_ know how to extract the $\epsilon$-factor -- he just applies the functor which sends the $(\phi,\Gamma)$-module to the corresponding representation and then gets the factor from there. But somehow the underlying premise of the question is that this isn't allowed.